# Figure created from contour changes to be in raster format when the number of rows and columns larger than some threshold

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, vector-graphics

A 2D data matrix ([data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hzf75qiju6zsy9i/lsa2.txt?dl=0), 100 rows by 100 cols) was plotted using 'contour' function in matlab, and the figure was saved as *.emf file. Expectedly when I insert the emf figure into MS word file, the figure is a vector graphic. But when I improve the resolution of the data, i.e. using imresize in matlab to scale the data matrix with factor 2, and did the same thing as before (plot, save as emf and insert it into word), the figure change to raster format. Is there any settings in matlab that can improve the threshold that keeps vector graphics? The code used is as follows:

```
path = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\';
data = importdata([path, 'lsa2.txt'], ' ', 6);
cdata = data.data;

% scale = 2;
% cdata = imresize(cdata, scale);
n = 25;
contourf(cdata,n, 'LineStyle', 'none');
colormap(jet);
axis equal;
```

Comment: If you want explicit vector graphics, use an explicit vector graphics format to be sure

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use imresize if you want a vector image. Imresize is by default raster based and can act weird. Also be more specific with what you want please. If you already have a vector file you can just change it to any size.

Also if you have only a limited data set, you can never really get a true higher resolution, you can only interpolate inbetween points. So use [interp2](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html) to resize your data matrix.

```
[sx,sy] = size(cdata);
fact=1/4; %factor to interpolate over so 4 points per 1
[X,Y]=meshgrid(1:sx); %you can only use this because cdate is square, same size for sx and sy
[xq,yq]=meshgrid(1:fact:sx); %create a new mesh with more points
Cnew=interp2(X,Y,cdata,xq,yq,'spline'); %I suggest spline, probably does what you want
```

[image]

This is the entire code to generate the plot, make sure to save it as an .emf, .svg or .eps if you want a vector image

```
data = importdata('lsa2.txt', ' ', 6);
cdata = data.data;

rws=3
cls=2;
xl=[22 33]; yl=[13 23];
n = 25;
subplot(rws,cls,1)
contourf(cdata,n, 'LineStyle', 'none');
title('Subplot 1: Original no scaling')
colormap(jet);
axis equal;
xlim(xl);
ylim(yl);

scale = 4;
cresi = imresize(cdata, scale);
subplot(rws,cls,2)
contourf(cresi,n, 'LineStyle', 'none');
title('Subplot 2: Imresize function, scale 4')
colormap(jet);
axis equal;
xlim(scale*xl);
ylim(scale*yl);

[sx,sy] = size(cdata);
fact=1/4; %factor to interpolate over so 4 points per 1
[X,Y]=meshgrid(1:sx); %you can only use this because cdate is square, same size for sx and sy
[xq,yq]=meshgrid(1:fact:sx); %create a new mesh with more points
Cnew=interp2(X,Y,cdata,xq,yq);

subplot(rws,cls,3)
contourf(Cnew,n, 'LineStyle', 'none');
title('Subplot 3: Interp2 "linear", scale 4')
colormap(jet);
axis equal;
xlim(xl/fact);
ylim(yl/fact);

[sx,sy] = size(cdata);
fact=1/4; %factor to interpolate over so 4 points per 1
[X,Y]=meshgrid(1:sx);
[xq,yq]=meshgrid(1:fact:sx);
Cnew=interp2(X,Y,cdata,xq,yq,'spline');
subplot(rws,cls,4)
contourf(Cnew,n, 'LineStyle', 'none');
title('Subplot 4: Interp2 "spline", scale 4')
colormap(jet);
axis equal;
xlim(xl/fact);
ylim(yl/fact);

Cnew=interp2(X,Y,cdata,xq,yq,'cubic');
subplot(rws,cls,5)
contourf(Cnew,n, 'LineStyle', 'none');
title('Subplot 5: Interp2 "cubic", scale 4')
colormap(jet);
axis equal;
xlim(xl/fact);
ylim(yl/fact);

Cnew=interp2(X,Y,cdata,xq,yq,'nearest');
subplot(rws,cls,6)
contourf(Cnew,n, 'LineStyle', 'none');
title('Subplot 6: Interp2 "nearest", scale 4')
colormap(jet);
axis equal;
xlim(xl/fact);
ylim(yl/fact);
```

Comment: "imresize" is just used to copy and enlarge the data, it did not involve in whether it is raster based or vector based. And your code did not work.

Comment: @emberbillow what error did the code give, there might be a small error or typo.